# Rails gem invalid date problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I want to update Rails Gem I've faced this problem

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/cucumber-1.0.6.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2011-09-13 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

Why does this problem occur?
and
How should I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug with rubygems. You can see the [commit that fixed it](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/21cccd55b823848c5e941093a615b0fdd6cd8bc7).

Try updating your rubygems install. On a related note, other Cucumber users have had [similar issues](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/136), but someone [reports a fix](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/136#issuecomment-2075306).

In essence:

1. Update rubygems.
2. Manually remove Cucumber gemspec and gem folder
3. Update bundler
4. Reinstall Cucumber
5. Try update Rails gem